# Need guidance to Increase request traffic on our project

Tags: mysql, mongodb, performance, yii2, http-post

We are facing an issue with the database on our project.

We want to support at least 20 requests per second but if we go to this number (with stress-testing setup) our database or something else on our setup can not cope with this load even if the actual request’s code is disabled (this means that the API only checks if the user is a valid one and don’t make the whole job that supposed to do). The users’ table at this time is under 100 rows with 10 columns.

The stack is built with docker. We use `MySQL 8.0.14`. The project is written on `yii2` and we use the `ActiveRecord` to access the database on every query.

A request’s workflow is as follows. When a user makes an API request sends a JWT token along with it. Then the API asks a MongoDB for this token to verify that it is ours. If this is the case then with the userId from mongo we ask this user’s data from our MySQL where all the needed info for this user is stored. After that, we execute the request’s code.

The stress-test query that concerns us is when we simulate 500 users that make 1 request every 10 seconds and run for 3 minutes. In this test, we disable the request’s code and we only let the code where we check about the user's validity. Below are the results:

the program we use to simulate traffic [here](https://github.com/rakyll/hey)

Running: `./hey -c 500 -q 0.1 -z 3m`

```
  Summary:
  Total:        191.2756 secs
  Slowest:      19.9512 secs
  Fastest:      0.2022 secs
  Average:      9.1227 secs
  Requests/sec: 40.1306

Response time histogram:
  0.202 [1]     |
  2.177 [639]   |■■■■■■■■■■■■■
  4.152 [320]   |■■■■■■
  6.127 [750]   |■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
  8.102 [1355]  |■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
  10.077 [881]  |■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
  12.052 [671]  |■■■■■■■■■■■■■
  14.026 [2012] |■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
  16.001 [527]  |■■■■■■■■■■
  17.976 [25]   |
  19.951 [12]   |

Status code distribution:
  [200] 6550 responses
  [500] 34 responses
  [502] 609 responses
```

more tests can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Mg2SZHyqbsamrJ2cSspQr0OOhXmia8IVVMD2Nuy6jwY/edit?usp=sharing)

the tables the request access when it only validates the user

```
CREATE TABLE `user_profile` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `company_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `system_status` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `telephone` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `last_login_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `creation_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
 `modification_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `user_profile@email_uniqueIdx` (`email`),
 UNIQUE KEY `user_profile@telephone_uniqueIdx` (`telephone`),
 KEY `user_profile@company_id_idx` (`company_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_user_profile_w_company` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `company` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_c



CREATE TABLE `user_profile_role` (
 `user_profile_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `role` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `creation_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
 `modification_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_profile_id`,`role`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_user_profile_role_w_user_profile` FOREIGN KEY (`user_profile_id`) REFERENCES `user_profile` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci




CREATE TABLE `company` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `system_status` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `telephone` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `website` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `creation_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
 `modification_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `company@name_uniqueIdx` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci



mongo db


* This is the model class for table "UserProfileJsonWebToken".
*
* @property ObjectId $_id
* @property int $userProfileId
* @property string $value
* @property int $acquireCount
* @property int $systemStatus
* @property string $lastUseDatetime
* @property string $creationDatetime
* @property string $modificationDatetime
*/
```

when DB is not under load the request with the code enabled needs 361ms

Yii debug log for Post requests
[here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Ri-JLIFp2K1ATAVFBC1OEzdr1kQq6z9pLBlZVJHSQKA/edit?usp=sharing)

---

**1. update**
after disable debug mode and added cache

---

main-db.php

```
        'enableSchemaCache' => true,
        'schemaCacheDuration' => 86400,
        'schemaCache' => 'cache',
```

main.php

```
    'components' => [
        'cache' => [

            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',

        ],
```

i'am getting this results

```
Summary:
  Total:        187.0877 secs
  Slowest:      7.3969 secs
  Fastest:      0.1197 secs
  Average:      3.5332 secs
  Requests/sec: 48.1058

  Total data:   1239578 bytes
  Size/request: 143 bytes

Response time histogram:
  0.120 [1]     |
  0.847 [187]   |■■■■■
  1.575 [1633]  |■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
  2.303 [1078]  |■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
  3.031 [1102]  |■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
  3.758 [811]   |■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
  4.486 [628]   |■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
  5.214 [1172]  |■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
  5.941 [905]   |■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
  6.669 [687]   |■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
  7.397 [455]   |■■■■■■■■■■■


Latency distribution:
  10% in 1.1331 secs
  25% in 1.8714 secs
  50% in 3.3492 secs
  75% in 5.1533 secs
  90% in 6.2478 secs
  95% in 6.7027 secs
  99% in 7.2395 secs

Details (average, fastest, slowest):
  DNS+dialup:   0.0100 secs, 0.1197 secs, 7.3969 secs
  DNS-lookup:   0.0000 secs, 0.0000 secs, 0.0000 secs
  req write:    0.0001 secs, 0.0000 secs, 0.0115 secs
  resp wait:    3.5052 secs, 0.1163 secs, 7.3231 secs
  resp read:    0.0001 secs, 0.0000 secs, 0.0024 secs

Status code distribution:
  [200] 7446 responses
  [502] 1213 responses

Error distribution:
  [341]Post "http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/vehicle-locations": EOF
```

I am having a big improvement but more work is needed

Comment: 9 seconds it terrible.  Have you verified that MySQL is the problem?  Sounds like you are missing indexes on tables.  Turn on the slowlog.  Let's see some of the queries being used, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table(s) involved.

Comment: I have updated the post with SHOW CREATE TABLE and logs when DB is not under load the request with the code enabled needs 361ms

Comment: How does it look the database structures in mongoDB? Indexes?

Comment: look at the post for the collection for the token.
No indexes. The collection only has very  few entries I have the feeling that we missing something basic

Comment: Are you sure that you disabled debug mode and enabled DB schema cache?

Comment: What are the queries?

Comment: @RickJames I am sorry I am not sure what queries are you referring .the queries for the request can be found in the second google doc

Comment: @rob006 I have updated the post now I am having a big improvement  but more work is needed

Comment: Nobody will be able to profile your app here, there is too many variables that can affect performance (not to mention the code itself, which you didn't shared).